# How can I show that a combination of two continuous functions is also continous?

Tags: real-analysis

More specifically, let $f: [-1,0] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and that $f(0) = g(0)$. If then $h: [-1,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $h(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            f(x) & \quad x \leq 0 \\
            g(x) & \quad x > 0
        \end{array}
    \right.$

So I started my proof as follows: Assume $f$ is continuous on $[-1,0]$. Thus, for all $x \in [-1,0]$ and for all $\epsilon > 0$, there is $\delta_1 > 0$ such that for all $y \in [-1,0]$ with $|x-y| < \delta_1$, we have $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$. Also, $g$ is continuous on $[0,1]$. Thus, for all $x \in [0,1]$ and for all $\epsilon > 0$, there is $\delta_2 > 0$ such that for all $y \in [0,1]$ with $|x-y| < \delta_2$, we have $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$. So choose $\delta = min(\delta_1, \delta_2)$ such that for all $x \in [-1,1]$ and for all $\epsilon > 0$, there is $\delta > 0$ such that for all $y \in [-1,1]$ with $|x-y| < \delta$, we have $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$.

Then I would go on to prove that $h$ is continuous at 0 using the definition of continuity at a point (in this case, 0).

Is there something wrong with my proof? (I am positive there is)

Comment: It seems that $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$  depend on different $x$. You should fix one $x$ at a time and prove continuity of $h$ at that $x$. If you happen to pick $x \in [-1.0)$ you only need to utilize continuity of $f$ (you shouldn't have to invoke $g$ at all). Likewise, if you are considering a $x \in (0,1]$ you need only utilize continuity of $g$. It is only when you fix $x = 0$ do you need to involve both $f$ and $g$, and from your post it seems that you know how they will be involved.

Comment: The last part of the proof is missing. I think it qualifies as "something wrong".

Comment: Focus on the point $x=0$. Use right continuity to get $\delta_1$ and left continuity to get $\delta_2$. It's trivial everywhere else.